# How can I put my Borland C++ Builder 6 project into Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, borland-c++

We are putting our existing Embarcadero Borland C++ Builder 6 projects into the new free Microsoft source control called "Visual Studio Team Services" (aka online version of TFS or Team Foundation Server formerly called Team Foundation Service).

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs

How can I put my code from my BCB 6 project to use it with this system.

Of course I'd prefer to have IDE integration, but as long as I have some kind of GUI I'm fine with doing source code tasks outside of the BCB IDE.

Are there any BCB files that are binary and therefore might be an issue with comparing changes?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to use TFVC or Git for version control inside of VSO? I would suggest using Git, then you can use any Git clients/plugins that you like and still keep the code in VSO.

Answer (score 1):

C++Builder does not have any native TFS support (not even in the latest version), let alone any VSOnline support.  At least with TFS, there are third-party plugins to let C++Builder access TFS:

[SourceConneXion](http://www.epocalipse.com/scx.htm)

[TFS.us](http://www.seenus.de/software/tfs.us/index.htm)

For TFS, you can also use the standard TFS client GUI.  For Visual Studio Team Services, who knows.

Several files are binary, including RES and TDS, but you usually don't need to do diffs on those.  You should, however, make sure to set your DFM files to Text mode, as they are set to Binary by default.  DFMs are always binary in the final executable's resources, but the DFM source files can be either text or binary, and you will likely do diffs on DFMs from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the visual studio shell (aka 'team explorer everywhere') to do checkins etc 
and you could also use the power tools (tfpt) to give you explorer integration.